# Регулярное выражение. Вытащить тег.

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть, к примеру, строка:

```
<a onclick="if (screen.width > 1024) func('someParam');   return   false;" href="http://yandex.ru/?q=abc" class=""> back="a"</a>
```

Как с помощью регулярки, получить из неё вот это:

```
<a onclick="if (screen.width > 1024) func('someParam');   return   false;" href="http://yandex.ru/?q=abc" class="">
```

DOM и etc, пожалуйта, не предлагайте. Возможно ли это на регулярках?

Comment: HTML _можно_ парсить регулярками, но это довольно сложно. Вот вам [полный правильный парсер](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/276994). А почему "DOM не предлагать"? Это запрет от руководства, или вы сознательно ставите себе задачу посложнее?

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку.

> почему "DOM не предлагать"?

Нецелесообразно подключать большой объект ради маленькой задачи. Нужно пропарсить всего один-два тега.

Comment: @istem: Эх. Парсинг HTML -- вовсе не маленькая задача, особенно если вы не контролируете его создание. Вы видели полное правильное решение. Если вы можете гарантировать, что ваш HTML не использует Entity, комментарии, CDATA и т. д., то есть, если вы гарантировано парсите очень маленькое подмножество HTML, маленькое простое регулярное выражение решит вашу задачу. (Например, если вы парсите строго один фиксированный документ.) Тогда вы должны тогда сами явно или неявно придумать грамматику, которая приходит на вход вашему рег. выражению. Если нет -- я бы посоветовал честный парсер.

Comment: :) там даже на страницу не наберётся. Та строка, что в вопросе - это, пожалуй, пример с максимальной величиной строки. (ну плюс-минус)

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно только ссылки, то можно так:

```
<a[^>]*>
```

Comment: Если было так просто. Ваш вариант не подходит, так как прервётся вот тут: 

    onclick="if (screen.width > 1024)...

Comment: Тогда может быть так:

    /<a.*?(?:(<\/a>))/sui

Comment: Так с контентом захватывает. А его-то как раз и не надо.

Comment: Регулярки здесь могут помочь если только формат тегов будет одинаковым.

Comment: А вообще уже надоели вопросы с примитивными регулярками, когда же опять появится достойный вопрос? :\  
Вот то что ищете:  

    <a(?=\s|>)(?:"[^"]*"|[^>])*>

Comment: @ReinRaus: угу, `gt;` -- правильно, но `>` может быть в CDATA :-)

Comment: @VladD, значения аттрибутов не могут содержать секцию CDATA, вот комментарии могут быть :)

Comment: @ReinRaus: Хм, правда не могут? Комментарии, правда, тоже не сахар. ;-)

Comment: @ReinRaus, переделайте коммент в ответ. 
Вот, немного модифицировал:

    #<\w+(?=\s|/?>)(?:(["\'])[^\\1]*?\\1|[^>])*/?>#

Совсем плохо, не?

Comment: @istem, да, так гораздо лучше, но вопросительный знак лишний `["'])[^\\1]*`**?**`\\1` , потому что без него отработает быстрее (с точки зрения микрооптимизации), но результат будет тот же

Comment: @ReinRaus, > А вообще уже надоели вопросы с примитивными регулярками, когда же опять появится достойный вопрос? — Сложный вопрос что ли задать :) ? Не, ну я могу...

Comment: @СашаЧерных попробуйте :)